# strip display name when sending email

Tags: debian, email, postfix, dovecot

I'm running dovecot 2.2.27 with postfix 3.1.15.

I'm not sure how to articulate what I want clearly.  When I send an email from my email server, the recipient can see my display name that I can set using the SMTP settings of whatever email client.

example on my side:

```
SMTP server: blah.com
SMTP username: bradboy
SMTP pass: pass123
Your Name: Brad the Man
```

The recipient gets the email, and it looks like this

New email from "Brad the Man" bradboy@blah.com

That's fine, I don't care about this... I can change it to whatever, or leave it blank.  Fine and dandy.  What I don't like, is the recipient can see what I have them in my address book as.

For example, in my email client's address book, I might have the following entry:

```
First Name:  Ball and Chain
Last Name: Jane
Email:  wife@somewhere.com
```

On her side, she gets an email that looks like this:

```
From: "Brad the Man" <bradboy@blah.com>
To: "Ball and Chain Jane" <wife@somewhere.com>
Subject:  "Doing great honey, dinner tonight?"
```

How do I configure the server to strip the display name of recipients?  I've tested in both a software client, and from my web-based interface, and it always sends that display name out along with everything else.